# Git Merging one developer branch to another developer branch before merging both branches to master (the main) branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I need some advice here on git branching strategies

I am working on a development branch called branch 1

and my fellow developer working on another development branch called branch 2

we have been developing pieces of code for 2 months independent of each other and now we have come to a point where we need to use each others code.

So, my question is, if I merge branch which is branch 1 with my fellow developer's branch which is branch 2. Then later, when I push my branch to master and then my fellow developer also push his changes to master, could that result in an error or what is the right way to merge two developer branches and then we both can later push our changes to master.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a new branch (branch3) from branch1. then you can merge branch3 with branch2. at this point, you and other developers should work on branch3 (or you can create two separate sub-branches from b3).
when branch3 was ready you can merge it to master. this way you avoid any conflicts.